# Rails - Get the name from a has_many => through association as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models

```
class Mar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :baz
  belongs_to :koo
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :other_mars, :class_name => "Mar", :foreign_key => :b
end

class Koo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mars
  has_many :bazs, :through => :mars, :source => :baz
end
```

and from the model Baz I would like to get the has_many name as a string. In this example it is "other_mars"

The solution would have to work for any similar has_many relationship with a class_name passed to it.

I am using Rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9

Comment: The usual question in questions like this - what do you need it for?

Comment: I need it as part of a search gem. It searches through a has_many => through association fine, but once there is a name declared that is different than the class_name (like "other_mars" here) it breaks. If I was able to get that has_many name, life would be very easy for me :D

Comment: You mean sth like ransack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, the following code helps

```
result = Baz.reflect_on_all_associations.collect do |association|
  association.name.to_s if association.options[:class_name].present?
end.compact
```

In your case the above code results `['other_mars']`. i.e it returns all the `associations` declared with the `:class_name` key.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get the has_many name as a string. In this example it is "other_mars"

If what you are looking for is the related association for a model, in your case `Baz` open up your rails console in the project directory and type:

```
Baz.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
```

This will return an ActiveRecord object with the a list of the associations under the attribute `@name`.

So the name of the association to a string can be obtained by typing

```
Baz.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).name.to_s
```